# Find primes satisfying specific properties

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does there exist infinite primes $p$ such that either $(p^a-1)/2$ or $(p^a+1)/2$ is a prime power for some integer $a\geq 2$?

Comment: You are asking whether there exist infinitely many pairs of primes $p,q$ such that $|p^a - 2q^b| = 1$ for $a,b \geq 2$, and this looks like a variation of Catalan's conjecture (now a theorem of Mihăilescu). Probably the answer is negative.

Comment: @Stanley Yao Xiao Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(p^2+1)/2$ solutions are $7,41,239,63018038201,19175002942688032928599$.

For $(p^2-1)/2$ solution is $3$.

The Pell equation $x^2 - 2 y^2 = \pm 1$ has infinitely many integer solutions, not sure the primality constraints leaves only the above.

Comment: Heuristics would suggest that there are only finitely many primes p and q where $p^2 -q^2 = \pm 1$ given PNT and exponential growth of the Pell equation solutions.

Comment: @JoshuaZ Probably yes. There appears to be infinitely many prime $p$ and composite q despite the exponential growth. Your comment is missing a factor of $2$.

Comment: Yep, mean $p^2 - q^2 = \pm 1$.

Comment: Gah and somehow I dropped the 2 again. Figured out why though. This keyboard's 2 key is apparently sticky.

Comment: What about the solutions when the index $a>2$.

Comment: @MasterGang If a>2, even without the primality constraint abc implies the solutions are finite. Unconditional result will be hard IMHO.

Comment: @joro Thanks. I get it.